# Ember nested routed with dynamic segments

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember app that has a series of nested routes, each with dynamic segments:

E.g

/NestedRouteA/**argA**/NestedRouteB/**argB**

In NestedRouteB route's model hook, I use argA and argB to find a given resource.

The problem I having is the model hook will not get called when **argB** stays constant, but **argA** changes

E.g

If a user is /NestedRouteA/**1**/NestedRouteB/**1**, and then goes to NestedRouteA/**2**/NestedRouteB/**1**, the model hook I am expecting to get called does not.

Any ideas how I can force the model hook to get called?

Comment: Please post a jsbin or some code that we can work with.  Much more likely to get an answer that way!

But judging by what you have said, I would say one solution would be to setup the controller for NestedRouteB in the hook for NestedRouteA.  So something like `this.controllerFor('nestedRouteB').set('model', MODEL);`

Comment: how are you transitioning between the resources?  model hooks aren't called if you provide a model.

Answer (score 0):

I created a JS fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ssirowy/P2P9n/1/

```
App.ParentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(params){
       return params.parent_num;
   } 
});

App.ParentChildRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(params){
      var parent = this.modelFor('parent');
      var child = params.child_num;
      console.log("Retrieving model for parent/child combo");
      return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve){
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            resolve(child);
        }, 1000); 
       });
   }
});
```

The current version of the fiddle uses the latest Ember, and does not display the problem I had before.

If, however, you use <= Ember1.5, the problem shows itself.

I upgraded in my project and the problem went away.